# d3 tree problems updating last node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i've got a d3 tree but it does not seem to update the final node (breadthwise) at each level properly
the data looks fine and it should update
i've got a gist here: https://gist.github.com/ptah23/554815d5604fa5edc87bba1922421f0a

i'm trying to visualise minimax adversarial search algorithm for tictactoe.
you can see it in action here:
https://gist.run/embed.html?id=554815d5604fa5edc87bba1922421f0a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you stop your `update` too early.

Try change your code to

```
var update = function() {
    if (!curNode) {
        clearInterval(timer); // remove return here!
    }

    ...

    if(curNode) { // wrap into "if"
        curNode = depthFirstIteration(curNode);
    }
}
```

`showUtility` is changed to `true` for the rightmost mode only at the last iteration but you don't update canvas after that and thus stuck with nodes without labels.